# How to convert Access query with prompt to T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am converting my Access query to SQL view. One of the Access query has where condition where a user can input values

```
where table1.id=[Enter the ID of the user]
```

Is there a way to convert a query like this to T-SQL. It is important for me to leave the prompt as it is.

Comment: No, you cannot use the MS-Access text unchanged with MSSQL.  Frankly, I would consider re-writing it as a [Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017).  Q: How will the user be inputting values?  For example, will you be writing a C#/Winforms app?  An Asp.Net MVC web app?  "Something else"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first, there is little reason to convert to a pass-though query.

However, SQL Server cannot prompt you in access (or say a web site that uses SQL Server). So the GUI part must be created by YOUR web site, or say access client in this case.

It is usually best to build some prompt form with a button, since those automatic prompts that Access creates are VERY poor from a UI point of view.

As noted, it is VERY likely that you can just continue to use the access query.

However, if you need a pt query, then you use access code to ask/get the prompt value, and then add that to your query.

This will work:

```
  Dim strSQL     As String
  Dim invoiceNum As String

  strSQL = "select * from tblInvoices where invoiceNumber = "

  invoiceNum = InputBox("enter Invoice Number")
  If invoiceNum = "" Then Exit Sub

  strSQL = strSQL & invoicenumber

  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
     .SQL = strSQL
  End With

  ' now, docmd.OpenReport, or openform or
  ' whatever it is you wanted to do with the sql
```

However, as noted, for reports etc., I would build a nice form that allows the user to enter a value. The query prompts are pure torture to your users, and they are not user friendly at all.

Also, the above assumes that you going to open some report, or some such. If you need the data returned in a reocrdset, the use this:

```
  Dim strSQL     As String
  Dim invoiceNum As String
  dim rst        As DAO.RecordSet

  strSQL = "select * from tblInvoices where invoiceNumber = "

  invoiceNum = InputBox("enter Invoice Number")
  If invoiceNum = "" Then Exit Sub

  strSQL = strSQL & invoicenumber

  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
     .SQL = strSQL
     Set rst = .OpenRecordset
  End With
```

And last but not least, as others suggested here, you should consider a stored procedure with parameters, as the above is subject to SQL injection.